# Electric Field at an Arbitrary Point due to a Uniformly Charged Disk

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I have been given the following question:

> Consider a slab of thickness $2R$ that extends to infinity along the other two dimensions.
>   The slab carries a uniform charge density $\rho$ with the exception of a circular cavity that
>   is carved out from the slab. The cavity has a radius $R$. The accompanying diagram
>   helps visualize this configuration:

[image]

The first part of the question asks:

> Find the electric field everywhere in space.

Isn't this kind of a hopeless task? Yes, I know how to compute the $E$ field due to an infinite slab -- infinite with a finite thickness. I also know how to compute the potential due to a uniformly charged disk *on the symmetry axis.* But isn't having to calculate the electric field at *any* point in space, which in this case would be a suitable superposition of the previous two cases, a bit too much. For example, related to the problem of a a unifiromly charged disk, Purcell and Morin's textbool *Electricity and Magnetism* reads:

> It is not quite so easy to derive the potential for general points away
>   from the axis of symmetry, because the definite integral isn’t so simple.
>   It proves to be something called an elliptic integral. These functions are
>   well known and tabulated, but there is no point in pursuing here mathematical
>   details peculiar to a special problem. However, one further calculation,
>   which is easy enough, may be instructive.

How should I go about the problem? No solutions, only hints. I'd like to work it out on my own.

P.SL We haven't done special functions in the course uptil now so I guess no one really expects us to use those in this problem.

Comment: I cant see how you can go beyond setting up a good coordinate system and writing out a genralised integeral in terms of the parameters known.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284147/gausss-law-for-cylinder-with-infinite-height-with-a-spherical-cavity/284192#284192

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way would be to fill in the cavity and calculate the field at a point. Then take the cylinder separately and again calculate the field at that point, and then vectorially subtract the field due to cylinder from the field due to slab.

P.S: Setting O as the origin (arbitrary point on the cylinder's central axis) the answer is rho*R/2epsilon knot . R is greater than 2R. For lesser than 2R and further lesser than R, you follow the same method

Comment: Yeah, but that's the problem. It seems it's a horrendous job to calculate the the $E$ field at an arbitrary point due to the circular/spherical cavity.

Comment: Why? Spherical cavity is easy and can be related to the gravitational field calculations (after adjusting constants and stuff) and even for cylinders it will be easy by considering a cylinder to be a wire with lambda as the charge density. Gauss' law comes in.

Comment: Umm, perhaps the question is ambiguously phrase, and I don't understand it correctly. I'm not sure if it is a uniformly charged disk/spherical shell or is it a uniformly charged infinitely long cylinder -- whose cross section, which is shown in the diagram, is a circular disk. If the case is the latter, the problem should be tractable: Gauss' Law for 2 infinite geometries; and superposition comes to the rescue.

Comment: If it's the former, see the comment above and the link: http://student.ndhu.edu.tw/~d9914102/Teaching/EM/Paper/data/Off-axis%20electric%20field%20of%20a%20ring%20of%20charge_Project%20Paper.pdf

Comment: I agree with Junaid - this doesn't answer the question. This technique is assumed known in the original post; the real problem is calculating the field of the slab, which is much harder than you give it credit for.

Comment: The question is to derive the net electric field everywhere in space. And I don't see any ambiguity in the question. Just a plain problem. Sigma/epsilon knot minus lambda/2piR

Comment: The method I proposed has no issues and if it isn't so, then please elaborate

Comment: In the above comment, lambda and sigma shall be written in terms of rho

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I also think that the question is ambiguously phrased. Could it be the case the we've only been shown a cross section (circular cavity) of what actually is an infinitely long cylinder (containing no charge) running through the infinite slab -- infinite sheet with a finite thickness. If this is the case, we should be good, right? Two infinite geometries implore us to use Gauss' Law and the principle of superposition.

Comment: Setting O as the origin (arbitrary point on the cylinder's central axis) the answer is rho*R/2epsilon knot . R is greater than 2R. For lesser than 2R and further lesser than R, you follow my same method

Comment: Yes, that's the case Junaid

Comment: @PranshuMalik My instructor just emailed me with the following: "Show results (electric field) for all points in a vertical plane. The cavity is bounded and spherical. " I'm still a bit confused. What exactly is the geometry of the cavity -- and where do we have to compute the $E$ field? -.-

Comment: @EmilioPisanty See the above comment.

Comment: @junaid If the cavity is spherical then the calculation is trivial.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty My best guess: Taking the origin to be at $O$, we have a system that can be thought of as a superposition of i) an infinite slab (infinite sheet with a finite thickness) of positive charge and ii) a sphere of radius $R$ centered at $O$ that is negatively charged. The superposition of these two will give the relevant geometry: slab with a charge free cavity. Just use Gauss' Law for an infinite slab and a sphere. The sphere will have its $E$ field in the radial direction and the slab will have its $E$ field in the $z$ direction. Convert $\hat{r}$ to Cartesian components and add.

Comment: That's what I make of this question now.

Comment: Yes that is indeed correct!

Answer (score 0):

Just to set this in more permanent form: yes, the task as you have (reasonably) construed it is pretty hopeless. This seems to be poor writing on the question on the part of your instructor.

- The question asks

  > The slab carries a uniform charge density $\rho$ with the exception of a **circular** cavity that is carved out from the slab.

  Your interpretation of this statement is reasonable and it is the only thing that one would expect from such a statement: a plane slab with a cylindrical cut-out, or more specifically charge filling the set
  $$S_1=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3: -d<z<d \text{ and } x^2+y^2>R^2\}.$$
- The way to solve this is to interpret the distribution as a solid slab superposed with a circular 'hockey puck',
  $$S_2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3: -d<z<d \text{ and } x^2+y^2<R^2\},$$
  of opposite charge. It is a hopeless task to calculate the field of this thickened disk anywhere but on its axis of symmetry - and certainly not without some very significant involvement of special functions.
- Your lecturer then comments that

  > The cavity is bounded and spherical.

  This is at odds with the question statement but it usefully narrows down the set in question to
  $$S_3=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3: -d<z<d \text{ and } x^2+y^2+z^3>R^2\},$$
  which *can* be solved exactly (as long as $R<d$, that is).
- To do this, simply superpose the field from a thick slab (easy) with the field from an oppositely charged sphere (easy). It will be a slightly messy piecewise affair, but each component is simple.